# How to keep DropBox daemon up-to-date?

Tags: upgrade, scripts, dropbox

I use DropBox to sync some files with an online backup I have, all has been going well except for recently I realised that DropBox regularly release updates and my installation does not alert me about them nor tell me how to upgrade. So I basically just want to know if there is an easy solution to be able to check the current installed version, and then if it is out-of-date, to update it to the latest version? I would like to be prompted though when it needs an upgrade.

I installed it with (as directed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx)):

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

Would I just need to run this command again to upgrade it to the latest version or would anything extra need to be done? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

A script which would check if there is a new version available and then upgrade if there is would do (I would just run it when I run my other upgrade commands).

Comment: Do you see anything related to Dropbox in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @edwinksl: Nope, nothing there.

Comment: I have Dropbox 5.4.24. It updates automatically and doesn't need `sudo`. All the Dropbox files are in `~/.dropbox` and `~/.dropbox-dist`. I too installed it as described in your question.

Comment: @DKBose: Well mine clearly doesn't... It's still on an old version... Which version started doing auto-updates?

Comment: How old? Dropbox does staggered updates. But if you are off by several versions, then that's a matter of concern. I'm sorry, I can't tell when the autoupdates started.

Comment: If you have all your data safely backed up, I'd just delete the two dropbox folder I mentioned and start afresh. BTW, I got the last update yesterday. And no, there's no notification at all. It's just that I use customized dropbox icons and each time there's an update, my icons are replaced by the stock icons. That's how I can tell :)

Comment: @DKBose: Well I still have the version just before the version you are running (I did a reinstall recently)... Please post [an answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791302/how-to-completely-remove-dropbox-daemon) about the removing of those folders.

Comment: @DKBose: Look, it really is very simple, could you please just post the answer that you posted on this question, on this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/791302/how-to-completely-remove-dropbox-daemon If you don't get round to it soon, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/246, I suggest adding Dropbox's APT repository to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu xenial main"
```

Then, import Dropbox's GPG keys using:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 1C61A2656FB57B7E4DE0F4C1FC918B335044912E
```

Comment: I'm assuming I have to uninstall DropBox first? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. `apt` should be able to figure out if there are newer packages in the APT repository than the ones you have, right?

Comment: Well, as the installation didn't involve `apt` nor `dpkg` at any point to my knowledge that may not be the case...

Comment: I'll post another question on it.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure I'd go that route. I think that link is quite old.

Comment: @DKBose: Seems to still be releasing updates for the latest distro versions and as I prefer to update software through the standard system rather than it doing it by itself, I think I'll probably go with this option.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox consist of two parts. Deb package only contains nautilus integration libs and python script to manage daemon, but the daemon is not present in deb package.

Daemon is downloaded after first run of dropbox and auto updated by itself.

In other words there is no benefit with adding dropbox into apt sources as only thing that can get actually updated is nautilus integration files.