# How to completely remove DropBox daemon?

Tags: dropbox, software-uninstall

I installed the DropBox daemon following [these instructions](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) with:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

But now I have found out that there is a more proper way of installing it through their official repository and APT. So how can I fully remove the version that I installed? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Comment: Possibly dumb question, but why not use `apt-get purge packagename`? That should remove everything whether you installed it via the official sources or a downloaded .deb, correct?

Comment: @TomBrossman: Because it wasn't installed using `apt`, nor `dpkg`, so it won't be registered under either. It was a custom install.

Comment: Maybe I'm remembering incorrectly but I thought it would still work if you get the package name(s) right. Anyhow, why not try `which packagename` to see where it's installed and then `rm <whatever-the-results-were`.

Comment: @TomBrossman: If it's a deb file, an actual 'package', yes, but if a command just downloads and runs a file which unpacks itself in my home directory and then I manually run it then it can't know. What would you have it do? Monitor every file I download and then execute?

Comment: `which` returns absolutely nothing because I manually run the executable file, there is no registered command.

Comment: That's obviously unreasonable so no, I wouldn't expect it to do that. Next question, if this isn't an installed .deb but is as you say an unpacked file in your home directory, what's stopping you from simply deleting the unpacked file(s)? I'm sorry I guess I'm not really understanding your goal here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41662/discussion-between-tom-brossman-and-paranoid-panda).

Comment: @TomBrossman: Deleting `~/.dropbox` and `~/.dropbox-dist` seems to have done the trick. Could you post that as an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to delete the files unpacked from the tar archive into `$HOME`. They'll probably be in a single directory, though that depends on how Dropbox made the tar file. Either way, they'll all be in your `$HOME` directory.

However, executing the daemon may have created some config files or other odds and ends. Your might run a `find $HOME -iname *dropbox*` and see if anything turns up. (Sounds like it may create a `~/.dropbox` and a `~/.dropbox-dist`)

Comment: There might also be a dropbox script in `/etc/init.d`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you installed dropbox the way you did, it will install it from  its official repository.

You may run

`apt-cache policy dropbox`

to see the origin.

However, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/uninstall-dropbox) are instructions on how to uninstall Dropbox.
The last command should be

`sudo rm -v /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list*`

to delete the repository from the list of available repositories. Besides, you have to use `sudo` to remove anything from /var/lib/, if there is anything that you should delete there.